# Non instantaneous/jerky movement using SDL2 & OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, events, camera, sdl

I've been working on a little 3D engine trying to fix up the camera and make it less jerky. I've been using SDL for the input and while it works it's doing this thing where if I press and hold a button it will instantly move once then pause and then start moving properly making the movement feel unresponsive.

I recorded a GIF of it and while it may be slightly hard to see what's happening hopefully it'll give some idea:

[image: gif]

Moving forward and then right would be like:

w   wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww a   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

The important code is here but feel free to ask for more if necessary:

```
//Poll events
    SDL_Event event;
    while (m_EngineState != EngineState::EXIT)
    {
        m_last = m_current;
        m_current = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
        deltaTime = (double)((m_current - m_last) * 1000 / SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency());

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                m_EngineState = EngineState::EXIT;
                break;

            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                break;

            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                m_Keys[event.key.keysym.sym] = true;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:
                m_Keys[event.key.keysym.sym] = false;
                break;
            }
            ProcessEvents();
        }

void Engine::ProcessEvents()
{
    if (m_Keys[SDLK_w])
    {
        m_Camera->MoveForward(5.0f*(deltaTime*0.001));
    }
    if (m_Keys[SDLK_s])
    {
        m_Camera->MoveForward(-5.0f*(deltaTime*0.001));
    }
    if (m_Keys[SDLK_d])
    {
        m_Camera->MoveRight(5.0f*(deltaTime*0.001));
    }
    if (m_Keys[SDLK_a])
    {
        m_Camera->MoveRight(-5.0f*(deltaTime*0.001));
    }
}

void Camera::MoveForward(float amount)
{  
    m_pos += m_forward * amount;
}

void Camera::MoveRight(float amount)
{
    m_pos += glm::cross(m_forward, m_up) * amount;
}
```

Comment: First of all I would make sure there is no performance issue. How many FPS do you have?

Comment: Why do you call `ProcessEvents` inside event loop? Shouldn't it be called once per frame regardless on how many events are here?

Comment: By the way behaviour you've explaied is called 'key repeat'. It is the same if you press a letter button here in your question edit and hold it - first press, pause, then continuous repeat. Both pause and repeat interval are controlled by OS/display server.

Comment: My FPS is easily 100+ Nica and keltar I guess because I wanted to split the event processing away from the main engine loop to try and prevent it being too messy and cluttered. It's not all properly organised yet because I was just trying to sort this out and thanks for your second comment, that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: It isn't about organised, it just wrong. Say I move mouse pointer quickly, press multiple buttons, have some events from gamepad, etc.., and you call moveforward how many times at this frame? While it should be just 1. Or if there is no events at all (e.g. key repeat is disabled), and you don't move at all while you should.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, I moved the processevents call out of the event loops, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use `SDL_PollEvent` with the `SDL_KEYDOWN` and `SDL_KEYUP` events, it is subject to OS keyboard repeat rates. Which is great for typing, but not for camera/player controls. Use [SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL)](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState) in stead to query the current state of the keys.

For example:

```
Uint8* keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_W])
{
  m_Camera->MoveForward(5.0f*(deltaTime*0.001));
}

if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_S])
{
  m_Camera->MoveForward(-5.0f*(deltaTime*0.001));
}
```

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense. So is all I need to do what you put there? Or do I have to make a loop kinda like with PollEvent to actually check for new events?

Comment: `SDL_GetKeyState` wouldn't update if you don't flush event queue, either with `SDL_WaitEvent`, `SDL_PollEvent` or `SDL_PumpEvents`.

Comment: Seems like GetKeyState doesn't exist anymore and was replaced with GetKeyboardState which I'm assuming works similarly so I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly thanks! Just needed to change around a few things and it works better than I expected. Accepted as answer though you might want to update it to say that SDL_GetKeyState has been replaced with SDL_GetKeyboardState.

Comment: @therealkf just so you understand - it is **very** similar to what you initially did in the question. SDL fills key state array based on the same events, and you did that yourself, so result is the same. Your only problem, as I've said before, was calling move inside event loop. Once you fix that both your version and this one will work because its underlying code is almost identical.